# How can a link in an ASP.NET master page be made to resolve relative to the page that is using the master page?

Tags: asp.net

I've found a fair amount of information on how to correct the use of relative links in a master page where absolute links should have been used, but I've not found anything yet about when relative links would be desirable.

The situation I'm facing is as follows:
I have a DataList acting as a navbar in my master page, which links to a page (`SelectItem.aspx`) in the root directory with a query string. I've created a directory called `Admin` which will hold a page with the same name.

I would like to implement the following behaviour:
When I click on a navbar link from `/OtherPage.aspx`, I should be taken to `/SelectItem.aspx`.
When I click on a navbar link from `/Admin/OtherPage.aspx`, I should be taken to `/Admin/SelectItem.aspx`.
The behaviour should be consistent regardless of the location of the master page.

My current implementation has the master page in the directory `/MasterPages/`, which results in all relative links resolving relative to that directory, rather than the directory of the page being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea, but you can do it by changing the master's `AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory` property:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = Page.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory;
}
```

Any relative links on the master page will then be resolved relative to the content page, rather than the master.

Comment: What negative effects could this potentially cause?

Comment: @grandta13: All relative links from the master page will be resolved relative to the content page instead. If all other links are app-relative or absolute, it should be OK. But if any are relative to the master, they will break.

Comment: @grandta13: It might be safer to isolate the navbar in a user control, and apply this code to that control instead.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. I decided to go the user control route.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
this.Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/path/to/some/page.aspx")
```

[ResolveClientUrl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how this answers the question.

Comment: I thought that it couldn't have been clearer. What are you confused with?

Comment: Here's more info (about `ResolveClientUrl` method): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I suggested adding more information because that way, instead of just solving the problem, you teach the reader what your solution does, so they come away learning something, not just copy/pasting. It was a semi-automatic comment because it was a single line of code, without linking to any documentation or explaining what the methods used are.

Comment: That's the right way to resolve a link relative to *the application*. The OP wants to resolve a link relative to *the current page*, which requires a different solution.

Comment: Even though the title of the question does indeed confirm that he wants results such as `../../another/path` relative to maybe `/some/path`, the content of the question suggests that he actually only wants to generate correct links, and how he'd be happy with `/another/path` in this same example - which `this.Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/another/path")` exactly provides. However, it's getting a little silly wasting time on discussing intricacies such as this. I'll edit my answer to remove the clutter and to make it complete (leaving just the code sample and the link to supporting documentation).